# MSbuild unable to delete file, access to the path is denied

Tags: typescript, msbuild

I am facing below issue while executing **clean** target for one of the csproj file. 
Error: 
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.3\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(325,5): error MSB3061: Unable to delete file 
"D:\Projects\editp.component.js". Access to the path 
'D:\Projects\editp.component.js' is denied**

I checked the permissions for the above path, it looks fine. Do I need to set any additional permissions for this file or folder? Somebody, please help me how to resolve this?

Comment: My first bet would be that the file is opened by another process. Can you delete this file manually?

Comment: @Filburt thanks for the response, I can delete this file manually. But why this error? this aborting our automated build.

Comment: Are you sure, the user account running your automated build has sufficient privileges? Maybe try running a cmd box as that user and try to delete the file manually as this user. Examining the Windows Event Logs may reveal more info. It's hard to tell without knowing more details.

Comment: @Filburt this issue is resolved after I removed read-only permission from the folder properties. Thank you

Comment: @Fiburt your comment helped me.  I could *not* delete the file manually.  There was a console window open that I needed to Ctrl+C close.